# Round down to 5 factor value in float value

Tags: python

I want to convert a float value to round down 5 factor value, this means for example `0.05,0.10,0.15`.

Suppose I have a value like `9.48`, and I want to convert it into `9.45`.

I tried with this:

```
val = 9.48
val - val % 0.05
```

It returns `9.450000000000001`. That is good for me but the problem is when I have `9.60`, it converts asn to `9.55`.

When the value is in already factor of 5 then it stays as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing

```
>>> val = 9.68
>>> round(val*20)/20.0
9.6999999999999993
```

Comment: Better to use round instead of int, result should be 9.7

Comment: thanks, but logic returns round up value. i want round down ,mean i want `9.65` for your example.

Comment: i think int() is working, but why 20? for multiplication and division??

Comment: @i'mPosSible `20=1/0.05`

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of [how floating point numbers are represented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) -- floats cannot precisely represent `9.60`. The closest (64-bit) float to `9.6` is just slightly less `9.6`, which is why the operation rounds down. If you need your mathematical operations to be precise then you should be using the `decimal` module rather than a `float`.

eg.

```
val = decimal.Decimal("9.60")
val - val % decimal.Decimal("0.05")
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html for an in depth explanation of floating point mathematics.

Comment: thanks, Dunes its work but in my side I don't use decimal, there is another solution with float or maths lib.